# Can't repair molecular relay?

Tags: fallout-4

So, I've just finished the Synth retention mission, and I have to talk to Father. I assume it means I have to go back to the Institute, right?

However, when I got back to Sanctuary Hills my molecular relay components had been damaged, and I can't seem to repair them, even though I have all the materials required :/

I can scrap them but there's no way to build them back, so...

Am I missing on something? How do I get back to the institute?

Answer (score 2):

You should have a miniature molecular relay that Dr. Li installed in your Pip-Boy. Just fast-travel.